# Can't change Google profile name

Tags: google-account

My brother somehow changed his 'real name' in his Google profile to something ridiculous and now can't change it back. It seems the only place we can find to change this name on *my* account is by clicking on the name in my Google+ profile page. hovering over it says "click to edit your name". Clicking on this link in my profile pops up a modal window which allows me to enter a different profile name. However clicking on it in his profile **does not bring up a modal window**. Clicking the link does nothing.

I'm guessing this is a Google+ bug, but until its fixed he's stuck with a stupid name. Is there anywhere else you can change this information in Google?

FYI: I've read all the pages I could find on this in Google help already.

Answer (score 5):

I found something interesting on this support article http://support.google.com/plus/answer/1228271?hl=en

On the page, it says

> If you created your account more than 2 weeks ago, you can change your name up to 3 times in 90 days.
>
> If you created your account less than 2 weeks ago, you can change your name more often.

It clearly means that you can change the name of a profile maximum of 3 times every 90 days. If you have already changed the name of the profile 3 times, you won't be able to change the name. You will again be able to change name after 90 days from the first name change in that 90 days period.

Answer (score 3):

Login to your Google+ account, open profile section from the Google+ menu or click here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/me and click to your name at the cover photo to edit your name.

Be aware of the Google+ profile name policy that You can change the name only 3 times in 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

After making the change, clear caches and then look for any changes. If it didn't worked, then check your profile details at Google Accounts here https://www.google.com/settings/account?ref=home

I think it's some problem with the browser, make sure you have enabled JavaScript and when you are on the Google+ profile page, let the page load completely and then click for the modal box to show up.

Use the latest updated browser, such as Chrome
https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/

Comment: we couldn't make the initial change because the dialog simply does not appear. I've edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: @roryok Updated the answer, please check.

Comment: I assumed a browser error, but there are no javascript errors in chrome inspector and the function works fine on my profile. I've checked multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix:

Go to settings, Accounts and Imports, and change the name under "Send mail as."

Answer (score 0):

Go to Gmail -->
Click on Settings wheel in upper right of screen -->
Click Settings in that menu -->
Choose the TAB called Accounts in the bar right under the word "Settings" --> 
On right side of screen at level of "Send Mail As", choose "edit info"
Voila!